# Magento profiling with XHProf

Tags: performance

What modules do you use in order to profile Magento with XHProf?

I tried:

- [liip / magento-xhprof](https://github.com/liip/magento-xhprof)
- [amacgregor / magento-xhprof](https://github.com/amacgregor/magento-xhprof)

Other options / approaches?

Answer (score 2):

I created my own library for the use of xhprof directly on specific part of Magento code.

```
 # File lib/Xhprof/Profiler.php
 <?php
 include_once "/var/www/xhprof/xhprof_lib/utils/xhprof_lib.php";
 include_once "/var/www/xhprof/xhprof_lib/utils/xhprof_runs.php";

 class Xhprof_Profiler
 {
     public static function start()
     {
         xhprof_enable(XHPROF_FLAGS_CPU + XHPROF_FLAGS_MEMORY);
     }

     public static function stop()
     {
         $xhprof_data = xhprof_disable();
         if ($xhprof_data) {
             $xhprof_runs = new XHProfRuns_Default();
             $run_id = $xhprof_runs->save_run($xhprof_data, "debug");
         }
         return '<a href="'.Mage::getBaseUrl('direct_link').'xhprof/index.php?run='.$run_id.'&source=debug">xhprof</a>';
     }
}
```

After that you could use

```
<?php Xhprof_Profiler::start() ?> // start profiler
    Your code to profile
<?php echo Xhprof_Profiler::stop() ?> // end profiler
```

So that everything works here is the installation procedure xhprof on debian server

```
aptitude install php5-dev make

cd /var/www/
wget https://github.com/facebook/xhprof/archive/master.zip --no-check-certificate
unzip master
mv xhprof-master xhprof
rm -f master
cd xhprof/extension
phpize
whereis php-config
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
make
make install
make test

vi /etc/php5/conf.d/xhprof.ini
[xhprof]
extension=xhprof.so
xhprof.output_dir="/var/tmp/xhprof"

cd /var/tmp/
mkdir xhprof
chown www-data:www-data xhprof

vi virtualhost
Alias /xhprof /var/www/xhprof/xhprof_html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xhprof/
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks there is an extension that offers basic integration:

- https://github.com/liip/magento-xhprof

Here a tutorial how to use it:

- http://matthewhaworth.net/installing-xhprof-on-magento/