# mage taking dobule time when theme is changed

Tags: optimization, profiler

i have changed theme after that when i debug using profiler ,my new website takes double time i tried to debug using profiler and found issue was with mage as it took double time when theme is just changed rest all backend and all is same .

is there way to further inspect why mage is taking double time

for old theme

```
Memory usage: real: 51642368, emalloc: 50489664

Code Profiler   Time    Cnt Emalloc RealMem
mage    2.4455  1   0   0
```

and for new theme

```
Memory usage: real: 51642368, emalloc: 50489664
Code Profiler   Time    Cnt Emalloc RealMem
mage    5.9360  1   0   0
```

Memory usage and emalloc remains same in both .

Need help in way to further debug issue

Comment: `mage` contains whole execution process time, please compare all of the other `profiler` values which helps you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed a commercial theme it happens.

If you experience the performance bottleneck on every page it could be the navigation menu: it is one of the elements that is present on almost every page.

I suggest you to use a more sophisticated tool to profile your Magento store like XHProf, refer to [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/magento-profiling-with-xhprof) for further information.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can u tell commention part of code in 1-coulmn-pthml and testing will help in finding issue??

Comment: yes, even if commenting out code to spot issues is a technique I would discourage to use because it can make you waste a lot of time; 
better spotting out the exact problem with a profiler

Comment: u mean using XHProf, is it different from magento built in profiler

Comment: yes, XHProf or Blackfire.io

Comment: can also tell ubantu or centos with is good for magento

Comment: hey i just commented whole 1-colmn.phtml still mage time was : 0.7140