# Filter collection on checkout/cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, collection

It is possible to do some collection in **checkout/cart** ? I tried this one but it doesn't work . My objectif is to get all items cart then filter them by attribute.

```
$_cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute', 'value')
    ->setPageSize(100);

foreach ($_cart as $item) {
    echo $item->getPrice();
}
```

or

```
$items= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
// I dont know if it is possible to add a filter on it.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `addAttributeToFilter()` does not work, because this collection is already loaded here.

To filter this collection can use `addAttributeToFilter()` and `getAllIds()` to just get the items you need.

```
# get items in cart
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$items->addFieldToFilter('sku', 75782007);

$itemIds = $items->getAllIds();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (in_array($item->getId(), $itemIds)) {
        var_dump($item->getSku());
    }
}
```

Comment: No, blank page: `$items= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();` `var_dump($items);`

Comment: @Prince please check updated answer.

Comment: I dont know too why the foreach gives the three ! But the workaroud i m not sur that it works and is the good one.but i Will tested it tomorrow. Logically you have three items id1, id2, id3. The $itemIds output the 3 ids and you compare them in the foreach in_array(...). In the first loop $item->getId() give you id1, it exist in $itemIds ok the 2nd loop id2 ok then the last 3 ok so logically you'll have the three items.

Comment: @Prince It's tested ... result is as expected, just can't explain "why" at the moment. Even `getAllIds()` is correct - otherwise it would not work.

Comment: Ok i'll feedback you.

Comment: @Prince Where do you want to get the filtered collection? In an observer?

Comment: No in a chekout/cart not in an observer

Comment: I just did the tests, indeed the foreach doesn't work, the workaound work, you know why just `var_dump($items)` returns nothing  or your `$items->debug()` ? i will post a new question about the foreach

Comment: @Prince i'm pretty sure this workaround is correct ... explanation here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/186001/46249

Comment: Yes @sv3n it really works but it doesn't mean that it's the best way :) for troubleshooting yes it will work. what questions me it's the `foreach` that doesn't work.

Comment: @Prince `foreach`  works as it should. It iterates over all 3 items, because collections IS already loaded. I think there is no better solution. `getAllIds` just runs one additional `fetchCol` query on entity_id column that has a small footprint, so dont worry about performance.

Comment: Are you sure @sv3n ? what about if i use a new collection `Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getCollection()` ?

Comment: @Prince Yes, I'm pretty sure about this. Creating a new collection takes more time/memory.  You can try it out using Xhprof (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11212/46249). Hope this solves your question about group products in cart too :P

Comment: Is it essential to install the Xhprof on server ? i tried just the firest and 2nd part but it doesn't work @sv3n

Comment: @Prince Essential? I use it for performance optimizations, but a long time ago that I installed that. Maybe this is more helpful ... https://sonnguyen.ws/install-xhprof-in-ubuntu-14-04/. If this doesn't work too, leave I comment ... will check this during next days.

Comment: i prefer the first link, yes i know that it's just for performance. i wanted to test it but i have some pretty error `lib/Xhprof/Profiler.php on line 9 //line 9 = xhprof_enable(XHPROF_FLAGS_CPU + XHPROF_FLAGS_MEMORY); ` but i just did create this class in `lib/Xhprof/Profiler.php` and i used it directly in some page like this: `<?php Xhprof_Profiler::start() ?> /
    some code
<?php echo Xhprof_Profiler::stop() ?> ` I have nothing installed in server side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62754/discussion-between-sv3n-and-prince).

Comment: Can you please leave some feedback? :) Still looking for a better solution? :)

Comment: No, I'm not looking for that at the moment, but i don't like much the workarounds

Comment: This is not a "workaround" per se. Since the collection is already loaded - adding one query to get results from same unloaded query is the fastest thing - I guess :P

Comment: and +1 for your time

Comment: Soon the `5000` points ^^