# Why does getSize() does not match cart collection size?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, filter, product-collection

Question popped up here: [Filter collection on checkout/cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/180110/46249)

Why does a filtered `$collection->getSize()` returns correct value, but iterating over collection has more items?

- three items are in cart
- want to filter one by SKU
- **result should be only one item**

Example code:

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$items->addFieldToFilter('sku', 75782007);
```

Using `var_dump($items->getSize())` correctly returns `int 1`, but ...

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    var_dump($item->getSku());
}
```

... results in ... (why?)

```
string '75782007' (length=8)
string '32811969' (length=8)
string 'hdd006' (length=6)
```

**Workaround:**

```
$itemIds = $items->getAllIds();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (in_array($item->getId(), $itemIds)) {
        var_dump($item->getSku());
    }
}
```

... results in ...

```
string '75782007' (length=8)
```

**Why is `getSize()` and `getAllIds()` correct, but does not fit to collection count?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry B00MER, Brett for wasting your time ...

All is working as intended ...

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
```

... just returns an **already loaded** collection that is stored in `customer/session` - so `addFieldToFilter()` has no affect here.

`getSize()` and `getAllIds()` gives "wrong" results because it does not count the items in that collection ... it's just runs another query to get number of rows or get the IDs where `addFieldToFilter()` is also applied.

So `$items->getSize()` returns `1`, but `count($items)` still gives `3`.

*Maybe someone can confirm this explanation?*

Answer (score 2):

There are methods on the collection used for iterating.  `getVisibleItms` is different from `getAllItems`.  Depending upon the type of product, it could actually be that this one product is made up of a group or selection of products.  Bundled products are an example of this.  You will see only one item in cart but in the raw data it will show multiple products.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have added 3 simple products to cart. Havent looked into code yet, but if i remember right `getVisibleItms` and `getAllItems` return array, no `Varien_Data_Collection` ... so it doesnt fit to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use the ORM methods as using PHPs `count` or looping over the collection is bad practice. The reasoning is most likely off by one errors, which you'll most likely find buried some where in the framework such as varien collection.

Details: 
http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf

*** EDIT ***
Link fixed.

Also the reasoning you'll find in the `Varien_Data_Collection` class, as I mentioned if you were wanting to iterate over the collection, you're much better off using an iterator like the class does as it's a part of the framework's ORM. most likely the one off is the fact that when `getSize` is called the returned value is set with `intval` into an integer. As a 0 will = false, on conditions, etc. Take a look at `getLastPageNumber` and it will make sense.

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.1/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php

As for a much better means of iterations without running out of memory on large collections is:
`// Walk through collection, for large collections this is much faster than using foreach
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($collection->getSelect(), array('productUpdateCallback'));`

Anyhow hopefully this explains it more.

Comment: Not really helpfull. I already use `getSize()` mehthod for performance reasons. Btw ... link is broken.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering :) I know about this stuff and also use it ... `foreach` was just for testing , to check if `addFieldToFilter` works. Update question tomorrow ...

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `getSize()` and `count()` is here [Marius explanation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4039/48355)

`getSize()` the collection is not loaded, `count()` it is, that why you get `int(1)` in `getSize()` and `int(3)` in `count()` .

Comment: This is already known and written in my answer. Btw ... this does not answer the questiom why its differnet for cart collection :)

Comment: If you create a collection with `Mage::getModel(catalog/product)->getCollection()` result is equal for `getSize()` and `count`, just differs in execution time. See here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179028/how-to-check-if-a-collection-has-items/179035#179035. But here (or more in your question) its not equal since collection is already loaded. Still +1 spending you time :P